# remove vertical lines from c3 step chart

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

The c3 step chart shows vertical lines. Is it possible to only show horizontal lines when plotted with bar chart. Also, for first and last bars in the graph, the step chart starts from center. Is it possible to make it start from start of bar.

[image]

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little hackery.  If you are using a recent version of `c3`, you can redefine the `d3` step line generator to suppress the vertical:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.2/c3.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.2/c3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script>
  
    function Step(context, t) {
      this._context = context;
      this._t = t;
    }

    Step.prototype = {
      areaStart: function() {
        this._line = 0;
      },
      areaEnd: function() {
        this._line = NaN;
      },
      lineStart: function() {
        this._x = this._y = NaN;
        this._point = 0;
      },
      lineEnd: function() {
        if (0 < this._t && this._t < 1 && this._point === 2) this._context.lineTo(this._x, this._y);
        if (this._line || (this._line !== 0 && this._point === 1)) this._context.closePath();
        if (this._line >= 0) this._t = 1 - this._t, this._line = 1 - this._line;
      },
      point: function(x, y) {
        x = +x, y = +y;
        switch (this._point) {
          case 0:
            this._point = 1;
            this._line ? this._context.lineTo(x, y) : this._context.moveTo(x, y);
            break;
          case 1:
            this._point = 2; // proceed
          default:
            {
              if (this._t <= 0) {
                this._context.lineTo(this._x, y);
                this._context.lineTo(x, y);
              } else {
                var x1 = this._x * (1 - this._t) + x * this._t;
                this._context.lineTo(x1, this._y);
                this._context.moveTo(x1, y);
              }
              break;
            }
        }
        this._x = x, this._y = y;
      }
    };

    d3.curveStep = function(context) {
      return new Step(context, 0.5);
    };

    var data1 = ['data1'],
      data2 = ['data2'];
    d3.range(5).forEach(function(d) {
      data1.push(Math.random() * 100);
      data2.push(Math.random() * 100);
    })

    var chart = c3.generate({
      data: {
        columns: [
          data1, data2
        ],
        types: {
          data1: 'bar',
          data2: 'step'
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @DmitryDemidovsky, just a little blurb in the [official d3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#custom-curves).  And [here's a more advanced example](https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/8f26a673f66801ab34ef0fa352662627) I did for a different stack overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

1. ***Vertical lines:*** I'm afraid that it's not possible, because step chart is drawn by a single SVG path.
2. ***Steps from center:*** You must be looking for [line.step.type](http://c3js.org/reference.html#line-step-type) option but unfortunately it appears broken in latest releases *(see answer and comment here: [c3 step chart align on event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162507/c3-step-chart-align-on-event/46175975?noredirect=1#comment87838313_46175975))*